# Filling a PictureBox of Type Rectangle, C++ WINAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, picturebox

I'm recreating an application that mimics the Windows Color Editing Dialog (ie from Paint), for study purposes.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGdtU.jpg

I created an identical looking Dialog, using PictureBox(es) as the "color containers".
I set the PictureBox type to "Rectangle", I figured it would be easier to use a LOGBRUSH to fill a Rectangle Object; instead of setting the PictureBox to type "Bitmap" and setting every pixel of the bitmap to the necessary color.

The issue I am having is... I don't know how to use the HWND of the PictureBox Control with the LOGBRUSH, to fill it.

I was having trouble finding the PictureBox Notifications and Messages to communicate with the Control.

Can anyone give me some insight in how to communicate correctly with the PictureBox Control?

Comment: It wil be in LPCREATESTRUCT if i remember correctly

Comment: You can try to find out if the control sends you a WM_CTLCOLORxxx (likely WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC) message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a static control with SS_SIMPLE style and no text. Then handle WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC message in the parent window. The parent window can then return the brush which the system uses to paint the background. Remember that its your responsibility to free the brush unless its a system brush. i.e if you have created the brush using CreateSolidBrush or similar functions, then you need to free the brush once it is no longer used, otherwise it will lead to GDI objects to leak. For the implementation you are proposing, you can have an array of brush handles created while initializing the dialog and supply appropriate brush for a particular box in response to WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC. And when the dialog box is about to destroy, you can free the brush handles.

Another way to implement is to create a custom control which only saves the colors for various boxes in an array in the window's private data, and draw them manually in response to WM_PAINT.